# Lost 15,000 reputation, userid changed, but user still associated with 470 answers!

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts

I'm not sure how but my userid on Stack Overflow changed from "progrmr" to "Gary A Morris" and my rep went from 15k+ to 21.   My "new" userid on SO appears to be user154803.  Questions that I've answered in the past are associated with "Gary A Morris" such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777460/154803). What's going on?

[user154803](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154803/user154803) - 1 rep, joined 3 years ago, no answers. Associated w/this meta account.

[Gary A Morris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777460/154803) - 21 rep, member for 5 days, 470 answers, answers from 2010?? Account is associated with the 1 rep SO account.

Comment: member for 5 days but you answered a question in 2010... what is this voodoo ;!?

Comment: Definitely a [meta-tag:bug]. I tagged it as such. Do you still have all your privileges?

Comment: Check out your accounts: http://stackexchange.com/users/51808/user154803?tab=accounts - you have 2 SO accounts with different userid's.  Weird indeed.

Comment: Have you looked at the [merge instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73801/137004) to see if one of the merging actions might have happened somehow?

Comment: Man, 102 upvotes on [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777460/154803), but you only have 21 rep.  You must have gotten a *lot* of downvotes.

Comment: Not sure I'd feel comfortable trying a merge. Who knows what could happen. Maybe wait for a dev :(

Comment: Looking into it now...

Comment: Try logging in again on Stack Overflow - I think everything should be back to normal.

Comment: I clicked on Gary A Morris, and it links to progrmr, a user with 15,244 reputation! Looks good from this angle. :)

Comment: It looks fine now.  That was strange!  Thanks for the quick action.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Could you post an answer explaining what happened?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail something hung up on a merge it appears, we'll dig deeper in the morning and follow up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jarrod and I tried to fix you up as soon as I saw the meta post, saved the investigation for this morning.  Let me know if you see anything else odd with your account and I'll get it fixed up.

---

So what happened was you logged in with another OpenID provider with a verified email address that matched your existing user, this triggers a merge of accounts. A merge is a 2 step operation:

1. Merge everything that matters to the master user (posts, name, oldest creation date, etc.)
2. Delete the child user which no longer has anything

Deletion is where this one went south, specifically a SQL timeout running in `.Delete()`:

```
update ModeratorMessages 
   set DeletionUserId = @comId 
 where DeletionUserId = @userId
```

This is a table where flags are stored, when a user is deleted their flags are moved to the community user.  In the merge case these were already moved over, but the `.Delete()` method is used for regular deletion as well so it runs a few extra things here.

Unfortunately `DeletionUserId` was *not* indexed and there was locking on that table at the time, causing your merge to not complete properly (some additional account magic happens after the child user is deleted).  The table has grown such that this column just needed an index (yes, when things get big you need indexes for deletes as well as selects!).  It shouldn't happen again, for *this* reason anyway.

Merges can and will fail in other spectacular ways in the future, of this I'm sure.  When those crop up, we'll have the same very detailed logging in place to track them down too.

Comment: Index all the things.